# Basic question about Wigner matrices & Peter Weyl theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I am reading a quantum gravity book and I have very basic question on the tools we use.

In the image below, they say that $L_2[SU(2)]$ can be decomposed into a sum of finite dimensional subspaces of spin j, spanned by elements of matrix of Wigner matrices.

So I understand this as :

$L_2[SU(2)]=Span(D_0^0,D^{1/2}_{-1/2,-1/2},..,D^{1/2}_{+1/2,+1/2},...,D^j_{m n},...)$

And for example $V_{1/2}=Span(D^{1/2}_{-1/2,-1/2},D^{1/2}_{-1/2,+1/2},D^{1/2}_{+1/2,-1/2},D^{1/2}_{+1/2,+1/2})$

Thus I have :

$$L_2[SU(2)]= \bigoplus_j V_j$$

with $dim(V_j)=(2j+1)^2$

**Why do they say that $D^j(U) : H_j \rightarrow H_j$ ($H_j$ is the vector space of dimension $(2*j+1)$) can be viewed as an element of $H_j \otimes H_j  $ ?**

I don't get it. It is probably very simple but I don't understand this.

[image]

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/299041/group-theory-character-representations-delta-function-unit-element/299135#299135). Instead of perorating on generalities, why don't you just take the traces of the rotation matrices D , so the characters χ, which are class functions and comprise a complete, orthonormal set of Chebyshev polynomials? [Behold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix#Orthogonality_relations)! The characters are so much handier than the Wigner-Ds themselves... 99% of applications in physics use *those*.

Answer (score 1):

The hom-space $\hom(U,V)$ is the vector space of all linear maps $U\to V$. There is a canonical linear map $U^{\ast}\otimes V\to\hom(U,V)$ which allows us to interpret tensors $\varphi\otimes v$ as linear maps $U\to V$. The interpretation is $(\varphi\otimes v)(u)=\varphi(u)v$ (which we "extend linearly" to allow sums of pure tensors to act as linear maps). When $U$ is finite-dimensional, this is an isomorphism.

Moreover, if $U$ and $V$ are representations, so are $U^{\ast}\otimes V$ and $\hom(U,V)$, and this linear map is an isomorphism of representations $U^{\ast}\otimes V\to\hom(U,V)$.

Finite-dimensional representations of $\mathrm{SU}(2)$ are self-dual, i.e. $V^{\ast}\cong V$, so we have

$$ \hom(V,V)\cong V^{\ast}\otimes V\cong V\otimes V $$

when $V=H_j$, which allows us to treat any linear operator $V\to V$ as an element of $V\otimes V$.

Comment: Sorry for the late comment. Just a question : you say that if $U$ and $V$ are representations, then the linear map is an isomorphism. But $U$ and $V$ are vector spaces, not maps so what do you mean by if they are representations ? You mean if it is a vector space attached to a representation ? But for all vector space I can find a representation attached to it ? I don't get this point.

Comment: @StarBucK This is a basic convention in representation theory, to refer to a representation by the letter for its underlying vector space. When $U$ and $V$ are representations, the map $U^{\ast}\otimes V\to\hom(U,V)$ is an isomorphism of representations.