# Peter Weyl theorem in $SU(2)$ : basis of $L_2[SU(2)]$

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, representation-theory

I have a very basic question about the Peter Weyl theorem in $SU(2)$. I don't want any generalisation, I just want to basically understand what the book precisely mean here. First some explanations.

The Peter Weyl theorem says that the entries of Wigner matrices form an ortogonal basis of $L_2[SU(2)]$. So this ensemble form an orthogonal basis of $L_2[SU(2)]$ :

$$ \{ U \mapsto D^j_{mm'}(U) \} $$ with $U \in SU(2)$, $j$ is the spin, $m$ and $m'$ are the line and columns entries of the Wigner Matrix $D(U),$ ($-j \leq m \leq j$ and  $-j \leq m' \leq j$) .

In my book it is written :

[image]

What I don't totally understand is in red. I agree that $D^j(U)$ is a map from $H_j$ to $H_j$ but :

- Why can we say it is an element of $H_j \otimes H_j$ ?
- And if we admit it, **we are talking about the matrices element $D_{mm'}^j(U)$ and not the map  $U \mapsto D^j_{mm'}(U)$**. In other words, on the lhs of 5.17 we have maps from $SU(2)$ to $\mathbb{C}$ and on the rhs we have linear map in a vector space (so at fixed $j$ it is map from $H_j$ to $H_j$). So, it is not the same "kind" of quantities and I don't understand

Comment: (1) The irreps are self-dual and $\hom(V,W)\cong V^{\ast}\otimes W$ as $G$-reps. (2) Map $L^2(G)\to \bigoplus_V {\rm End}(V)$ is given by $f\mapsto \bigoplus_V\left(\int_G f(g)\pi_V(g)\,{\rm d}g\right)$.

Comment: It looks like your (1) was also answered earlier in your [previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2316354/basic-question-about-wigner-matrices-peter-weyl-theorem?rq=1) (the same way).

Comment: @arctictern
Yes I totally forgot I already asked the question :O. It is ok for (1). But I am not totally sure to get (2). $L_2[SU(2)]= \oplus_j Span( \{ U \mapsto D^j_{m m'}(U) \}_{m m'} )$. So i have a span of elements of $L_2[SU(2)]$. You said that I can associated to them a direct sum of endomorphism with your map but why will be thoose endomorphism the representations ?

Comment: I can't understand what you're asking.

Comment: @arctictern could you re explain me the second point asked in my question. Elements of $\mathcal{H}_j \otimes \mathcal{H}_j$ are the maps $D^j(U)$ :they eat vectors and give vectors. They don't eat groups elements to give complex. And as we have $L_2[SU(2)]=\oplus_j \mathcal{H}_j \otimes \mathcal{H}_j$ i don't get it.  I think you answered it with your point (2) but I didn't understand it

Comment: Yeah, if $\rho:G\to {\rm GL}(V)$ is a representation, then for every $g\in G$, the endomorphism $\rho(g)$ eats vectors and give vectors. That's how repersentations work.

Comment: @arctictern
Yes but for me there is a problem. the rhs of (5.17) is not composed of representation but of representation evaluated on a group element : $D^j(U)$. We can see it because $D^j(U)$ is an element of $\mathcal{H}_j \otimes \mathcal{H}_j$. So it is a linear map $V \rightarrow V$. The lhs eats group element to give number. So it is not the same kind of stuff on the lhs and on the rhs. This is what I don't get

Comment: That's because it's supposed to be an isomorphism, not an equality. The stuff on the left are indeed complex-valued functions of group elements whereas the stuff on the right are direct sums of linear operators on irreps. But the isomorphism takes a function of group elements (an element of the left side, which if you interpret as a "formal integral over group elements" is a generalization of a formal sum of group elements as seen in the group algebra) and spits out a direct sum of linear operators (an element of the right hand side).

Comment: Would it help you to look at the characters, the traces of these D's, which are class functions, and just focus on the simple [completeness relation for SU(2) characters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wigner_D-matrix#Orthogonality_relations)?